# Latex multicolumn, multirow table

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

I struggle with a multirow, multicolumn table in latex. So far I have this (messy) code:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {A}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {B}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {C}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf {D}} && D1 & D2 & D3 &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf {E}}   && E1 & E2 & E3 &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {F}}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-10}
    a & b & c & d1 & d2 & d3 & e1 & e3 & e3 & f\\
    aa & bb & cc & dd1 & dd2 & dd3 & ee1 & ee3 & ee3 & ff
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Ideally the table would look like this:

[image: multicolumn, multirow table]

Subheader D1-E3 should not be bold....

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: welcome to TEXSE, could you make your script compilable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to clean your code a little bit.

Here is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{A}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{B}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{C}} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{D}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{E}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{F}}\\
        \cmidrule{4-9}
        &&&  D1 & D2 & D3 & E1 & E2 & E3 & \\ \midrule
        a & b & c & d1 & d2 & d3 & e1 & e3 & e3 & f\\
        aa & bb & cc & dd1 & dd2 & dd3 & ee1 & ee3 & ee3 & ff\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It renders like this:

[image]

However, if you absolutely need the vertical line, I have no idea how to do it on two rows only...

Enjoy!

Comment: No, the vertical line isn't a must. Thank your for your code. I got another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115402/latex-multirow-and-multicolumn-table#58115513 which introduces a small gap instead of the vertical line, also very nice layout. Anyway, thanks a lot for your prompt answer.

Answer (score 1):

I more like the following table design:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.5}{*}{\thead{A}} 
    & \multirow{2.5}{*}{\thead{B}} 
        & \multirow{2.5}{*}{\thead{C}} 
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{D}} 
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{E}} 
                    & \multirow{2.5}{*}{\thead{F}}    \\
    \cmidrule(l){4-6}   \cmidrule(l){7-9}
    &       &       & D1    & D2    & D3    & E1    & E2    & E3    & \\ 
    \midrule
a   & b     & c     & d1    & d2    & d3    & e1    & e3    & e3    & f\\
aa  & bb    & cc    & dd1   & dd2   & dd3   & ee1   & ee3   & ee3   & ff\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is the '2.5' first argument of \multirow the reason for which the A, B, C and F are centered regarding the \cmidrule commands, compared to my solution? I used '2' instead and I got a small shift.

Comment: @AlexandreQuenon, yes. With this is considered spaces around rules (below of `\toprule, around `\cmisrule` and above of the `\midrule`) which sum is about `0.5\baselineskip`. This is nice new features of recent ˙multirow` package.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to add vertical rules compatible with the horizontal rules of `booktabs` (which is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`) you should try `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the tabular and it's possible to use these nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{c}}
\toprule
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{A} 
    & \Block{2-1}{B} 
        & \Block{2-1}{C} 
            & \Block{1-3}{D} 
                &&& \Block{1-3}{E} 
                    &&& \Block{2-1}{F}    \\
    \cmidrule(l){4-9}
    &       &       & D1    & D2    & D3    & E1    & E2    & E3    & \\ 
    \midrule
a   & b     & c     & d1    & d2    & d3    & e1    & e3    & e3    & f\\
aa  & bb    & cc    & dd1   & dd2   & dd3   & ee1   & ee3   & ee3   & ff\\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw (1-|7) -- (3-|7) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score -1):

Added the vertical lines to @Alexandre Quenon (EDIT:Sorry got confused) solution

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{A}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{B}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{C}} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{D}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\textbf{E}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{F}}\\
        \cmidrule{4-9}
        &&&  D1 & D2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D3} & E1 & E2 & E3 & \\ 
        \midrule
        a & b & c & d1 & d2 & d3 & e1 & e3 & e3 & f\\
        aa & bb & cc & dd1 & dd2 & dd3 & ee1 & ee3 & ee3 & ff\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: it works but the problem is that you don't have a continuous vertical line, which is quite the opposite of what you usually want.

Comment: Yeah, it gets closer when you use \hline but then the head looks not so nice.

Comment: Instead of ```\cmidrule{4-9}``` you can consider using ```\cline{4-9}```